# Dictionaries with volatile values in Python unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test for a function that returns a dictionary. One of the values in this dictionary is `datetime.datetime.now()` which of course changes with every test run.

I want to ignore that key completely in my assert. Right now I have a dictionary comparison function but I really want to use assertEqual like this:

```
def my_func(self):
    return {'monkey_head_count': 3, 'monkey_creation': datetime.datetime.now()}

... unit tests

class MonkeyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myfunc(self):
        self.assertEqual(my_func(), {'monkey_head_count': 3}) # I want to ignore the timestamp!
```

Is there any best practices or elegant solutions for doing this? I am aware of `assertAlmostEqual()`, but that's only useful for floats iirc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just delete the timestamp from the dict before doing the comparison:

```
class MonkeyTester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myfunc(self):
        without_timestamp = my_func()
        del without_timestamp["monkey_creation"]
        self.assertEqual(without_timestamp, {'monkey_head_count': 3})
```

If you find yourself doing a lot of time-related tests that involve `datetime.now()` then you can monkeypatch the datetime class for your unit tests.  Consider this

```
import datetime
constant_now = datetime.datetime(2009,8,7,6,5,4)
old_datetime_class = datetime.datetime
class new_datetime(datetime.datetime):
    @staticmethod
    def now():
        return constant_now

datetime.datetime = new_datetime
```

Now whenever you call `datetime.datetime.now()` in your unit tests, it'll always return the `constant_now` timestamp.  And if you want/need to switch back to the original `datetime.datetime.now()` then you can simple say

```
datetime.datetime = old_datetime_class
```

and things will be back to normal.  This sort of thing can be useful, though in the simple example you gave, I'd recommend just deleting the timestamp from the dict before comparing.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that simple solution? Although I will be testing a lot of possible return values of my_func, so I think I will monkeypatch datetime as you suggested. Much appriciated, really clever!

Comment: You should put code to switch back the datetime in a teardown method -- that way this unit test won't affect other test classes

Comment: Another option is to pass in datetime.datetime.now as the default for a named parameter; pass in your own function in the unit test. This avoids monkeypatching.

Comment: Chrispy, a unit test shouldn't require modifying the code their testing.